# mysql outer join

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I'm trying to get the following result:

```
date  | country | type | amount
-------------------------------
21/09 | BE      | STK  | 20
21/09 | BE      | OPT  | 50
21/09 | BE      | CSH  | 0
```

based on the following tables

```
date  | country | type | amount
-------------------------------
21/09 | BE      | STK  | 20
21/09 | BE      | OPT  | 50


typeId | typeName                  typeName
-----------------                  --------
0      | STK              -OR-     STK
1      | CSH                       CSH
2      | OPT                       OPT
```

in plain text:
for every day, I want the amount for every type, and to have a 0 if there is no data available for that day.

MySql does not have an outer join, and I can't get it to work with a right join.
When I use a right join, I get a 'null' for everything except the type.

In reality there are 13 different types, and the other source table is not for a single day or a single country, but I suppose that that shouldn't matter.

Comment: MySQL has `LEFT` and `RIGHT` outer joins just fine. It's only lacking `FULL` joins but you don't need them for your query. Do you have a table with a list of dates for which you want these results?

Comment: It would also be good to show us the output of `SHOW CREATE tablename;` (so we know the table and columns names and types, etc.)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: it's for daily updates of an aggregate table based on production information. The typeNames and country are varchar(select distinct from AnotherTable), date is date(datetime) and amount is int.
I don't have a date table as such but I could make them with 'select distinct'

Comment: Use a left join from type to amounts, and substitute other values for any nulls that appear onthe right side of the join.

Comment: while no solution was given, I have found the right solution thanks to the input. Thank you guys so much.
@AndrewBrennan: basically what you said :D

Comment: I'll make it an answer then

Answer (score 1):

To get all types for a specific country and a specific date, you need a simple `LEFT` join from `types` to the data table:

```
SELECT 
    '2016-09-21'           AS date, 
    'BE'                   AS country, 
    t.typeName             AS type, 
    COALESCE(a.amount, 0)  AS amount
FROM types AS t
  LEFT JOIN amounts AS a 
    ON  a.date = '2016-09-21'
    AND a.country = 'BE`
    AND a.type = t.typeName ;
```

If you want all the options but for many countries or for many dates or both, you'll need to first `CROSS` join the `types` and `countries` and/or `dates` tables, then do the `LEFT` join.
If there isn't a `countries` or `dates` table, you can either use derived tables, either with `SELECT DISTINCT` or with a list of dates::

```
SELECT 
    d.date                 AS date, 
    c.country              AS country, 
    t.typeName             AS type, 
    COALESCE(a.amount, 0)  AS amount
FROM 
    ( SELECT DISTINCT country
      FROM data
    ) AS c                -- the countries table
  CROSS JOIN 
    ( SELECT DATE('2016-09-01') AS date UNION ALL
      SELECT '2016-09-02' UNION ALL
      ---
      SELECT '2016-09-30'
    ) AS d                -- the dates table
  CROSS JOIN 
    types AS t
  LEFT JOIN amounts AS a 
    ON  a.date = d.date
    AND a.country = c.country
    AND a.type = t.typeName ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a left join from type to amounts, and substitute other values for any nulls that appear on the right side of the join using `COALESCE`. e.g. Assuming two tables: amounts and types:

```
select coalesce (a.date, sysdate), coalesce (a.country,'BE'), t.typeName as type, coalesce (a.amount,0)
from types t
left join amounts a on t.typeName=a.type;
```